# Datatables and moment.js time filtering

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables, momentjs

I am using datatables v1.10.11 and Jquery v 2.2.0.

All is working as expected, however I would like to add another date filter to my existing datepicker.

I would like to filter items that are **older than 3 years** (as of today's date).

I was looking at http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-after/ but not sure if that's what I need, or how to incorporate it?

My code so far is as follows;

```
var table = $('#items').DataTable({});

$("#myInputTextField2").daterangepicker({
    autoUpdateInput: false,
        "ranges": {
        "Today": [moment(), moment()],
        'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
        'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
        'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
        'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
        'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')],
        'Last Year': [moment().subtract(365, 'days'), moment()],
        'Last 3 Years': [moment().subtract(1095, 'days'), moment()]
        // Over 3 years old option here
    }
});
```

Just to clarify, I would like to filter items that are **older** than three years.

The only way I can currently get it to work is set 'Over 3 years' as follows;

```
'Over 3 Years': [moment("1970-01-01"), moment().subtract(3, 'years')]
```

I'm sure there is a better way?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use

```
moment().subtract(1095, 'days')
```

It's not always "3 years", use

```
moment().subtract(3, 'years')
```

to consider leap years

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question? Could you state it more precisely?

Comment: I have changed this in my code and it works. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Your welcome. Would you mind to mark the question as solved?

Comment: My question still isn't solved though. My main issue still exists. I can't filter items that are older than three years. Your suggestion filters items within three years.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a minimal date?
So as the syntax is "from", "to" it could be something like

```
'Over 3 Years': [moment("1492-10-12"), moment().subtract(3, 'years')]
```

Comment: Yes. As stated in my question it will be from today's date. So basically items that are over three years old. Thanks for the suggestion.